# AJAX-Loaded Content Into a DIV.. Which Page Owns/Controls What?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using the jQuery load() function to bring some content from a secondary ASPX page into a DIV on a primary ASPX page.  The content in question contains a button control and a label control, with click event code for the button (residing in the code-behind of the secondary page) that subsequently populates some text into the label control.  The secondary page works fine by itself.

On the primary page, using the load() function brings the button and label into the DIV just fine.  What I'm trying to understand is where the scope lies for the loaded content.  It's now resident in the primary page's DOM, which to my mind suggests that it is under the control (if that's the right word) of the primary page.  However, clicking the button results in the secondary page 'taking over', with a refresh back to the secondary page with the text properly populated in the label.  This result would suggest that there is some sort of hybrid hierarchy in terms of page scope, particularly for that loaded button control and its related click event.

Is there a clear rule or definition that defines this relationship?  It's obviously critical to understand from a standpoint of coding pages that contain load()'ed content.

Thanks all.

Comment: Of course, yes. I'm just trying to understand where the client/server boundary is in a scenario like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML is now part of the primary page, because the jQuery `.load()` function returns HTML, not code, and the HTML is injected into the DIV. The button click code in the secondary page is not transferred to the primary page, thus you would need to wire up click event handlers in jQuery, like this:

```
$('#TheButtonID').live('click', function () {
     // Your code here for handling a button click

});
```

OR

```
$('#TheButtonID').on('click', function() {
    // Your code here for handling a button click
});
```

Note: It is recommended to use `.on()` in later versions of jQuery, but `.live()` was not removed until jQuery 1.9.x

---

It is possible to call ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods from a jQuery `.ajax()` function, but it would not be able to execute the existing click event handler code in the secondary .aspx page, because ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods must be static, as they can call code across page boundaries since the page instance is not there. This might be a better solution for you, where you have to duplicate some of your logic into a static method to be called by script, but remember that you cannot interact with any of the page controls, because the page instance is not there.

Comment: Not 100% true, if the ASP.NET return for example a <form> and a <submit> the ASP.NET code behind would execute just fine.

Comment: @Sebastien - you can only have one `<form runat="server">` in an ASP.NET page at a time though. I get your point, but it would most likely not work in the scenario described by the OP.

Comment: Still confused. The controls from the secondary page are rendered as standard HTML in the load()'ed primary page - I understand that. The button's markup, for instance shows the ID that I gave it originally in the secondary page. What still isn't clear is how/why the server code for the button click, still/permanently resident (I think) in the secondary page, is accessible by the button, now that it’s a part of the primary page's DOM.  They're separate entities (the primary page and its server code vs. the secondary page and it’s server code), right?

Comment: It's not like an <iframe> where everything is contained and isolated. The button, label (now a span) and other secondary-sourced HTML are now a part of the primary page. It seems completely illogical for the HTML from the primary page to have access to the server coding behind the secondary.

I’m sure that this is all core understanding of how AJAX does its thing but the governing rules for load()’ed controls are still as clear as mud to me.

Comment: @MinnRick - I am not disagreeing with you that the button itself and the logic that handle the click are now separated once the primary page loads the HTML from the secondary page.